# Admob not displaying interstitials after screen is loaded, only one time in some cases

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob

I'm displaying interstitials with admob 8.0.0 after new screen is loaded in my app, but something is wrong because the present function is being called but interstitial is not being displayed.

If I try displaying them with a button that calls the present function, then it's displayed but only one time, only the first time I press the button. If i press it more times, no more interstitials are being called, and the code is executing the line of the present function. None of the `GADFullScreenContentDelegate` delegate events are being called.

Can someone explain me what is wrong?

I'm loading interstitials this way:

```
self.gadInterstitial?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
let request = GADRequest()
GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID:self.adId, request: request, completionHandler: { [self] ad, error in
            if let error = error {
                logger.error(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            gadInterstitial = ad
            logger.debug("Loaded Ad Mob interstitial view")
            loaded = true
        }
    )

extension AdMobAdEntity: GADFullScreenContentDelegate {
    /// Tells the delegate that the ad failed to present full screen content.
    func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {
        print("Ad did fail to present full screen content.")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that the ad presented full screen content.
    func adDidPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("Ad did present full screen content.")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that the ad dismissed full screen content.
    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("Ad did dismiss full screen content.")
    }
}
```

I'm displaying them after new screen has been loaded, or when the button interstitial is pressed this way:

```
override func showInterstitial(viewController: SectionViewController?) {
    guard loaded, let controller = viewController else {
        return
    }
    gadInterstitial?.present(fromRootViewController: controller)
    logger.debug("Displaying interstitial view")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dismiss ads after call loadInterstitial() function

> ```
> func loadInterstitial() {
>     let request = GADRequest()
>     GADInterstitialAd.load(
>       withAdUnitID: self.adId, request: request
>     ) { (ad, error) in
>           if let error = error {
>             logger.error(error.localizedDescription)
>             return
>          }
>         self.gadInterstitial = ad
>         logger.debug("Loaded Ad Mob interstitial view")
>         loaded = true
>         self.gadInterstitial?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
>     }
>   }
> ```

> ```
> func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
>     print("Ad did dismiss full screen content.")
>     loaded = false
>     loadInterstitial()
> }
> ```

> ```
> override func showInterstitial(viewController: SectionViewController?) {
> guard loaded, let controller = viewController else {
>     loadInterstitial()
>     return
> }
> gadInterstitial?.present(fromRootViewController: controller)
> logger.debug("Displaying interstitial view")
> }
> ```

Comment: Hi, I can't understand you. Whad do you mean? I'm dissmissing the ads after loading them? I can't see that in my code

Comment: Also, as I told in my question, the delegate events are not being caled. adDidDismissFullScreenContent is never called.

Comment: @NullPointerException you must implement the GADFullScreenContentDelegate protocol and assign it to the fullScreenContentDelegate property of the returned ad.  Please add loadWithAdUnitID:request:completionHandler method in the self.gadInterstitial?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self line